# Adding space before and after paragraph

Tags: paragraphs, parskip

I am using `parskip` package in my document to get spacing between paragraphs. I can change skip amount using `\setlength{\parskip}{12pt}`. However, this only affects the space after paragraph. The styling document of the institute requires 6pt space BEFORE and AFTER the paragraph. How can I achieve this?

By the way, this is what I do at the moment:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{12pt} % Just changes spacing AFTER paragraph
                           % What to do to adjust spacing BEFORE paragraph?
\begin{document}
This is paragraph one.

This is paragraph two.

This is paragraph three.
\end{document}
```

Comment: can you make your question more clear by adding a minimal example of your code?

Comment: Isn’t that the same as 12pt *between* paragraphs?

Comment: I think it will make difference for the first paragraph and if there is an equation between paragraphs etc.

Comment: this example follows the rule that "space at the beginning (or top) is ignored unless it's explicit", and `\parskip` isn't explicit in that sense.  if you really need extra space before the first paragraph, `\vspace*{12pt}` is what you need -- that `*` is important.